# Visualforce page rendered as pdf on quote

Tags: visualforce, pdf, pageblocktable

How do I create a Visualforce page rendered as pdf with header and footer keeping 'Quote' as standard controller and displaying an image and table on the page. Show company address on top right and other companies logo and address on the top left.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="QuoteLineItem" renderAs="pdf">
<head>
     <style type="text/css" media="print">
                       @page {
                                 @top-center {
                                       content: element(header);
                               }
                               @bottom-left {
                                     content: element(footer);
                               }
                            }
                                     div.header {
                                      padding: 10px;
                                      position: running(header);
                           }
                       div.footer {
                                display: block;
                             padding: 5px;
                               position: running(footer);
                      }
                                     .pagenumber:before {
                                        content: counter(page);
                       }
                                   .pagecount:before {
                             content: counter(pages);
                        }
                    </style>

   <right>
<apex:image id="icon1" value="{!$Resource.iconlogo}" width="200" height="200" />

 <apex:outputText value="Icon Resources" />
  <apex:outputText value="A-34,2nd floor" />
   <apex:outputText value="Sector 2,Noida" />
    <apex:outputText value="Uttar Pradesh" />
    </right>


    <left>
    <apex:outputField value="{!quote.Account}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!quote.BillingAddress}"/>

    </left>

    </head>

     <apex:pageBlock >



            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!quotes.QuoteLineItem}" var="QuoteLineItem">



                <apex:column value="{!quotelineitem.quote}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!quotelineitem.listprice}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!quotelineitem.discount}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!quotelineitem.description}"/>



            </apex:pageBlockTable>



        </apex:pageBlock>

  <div class="header">
              <div>Quote</div>
           </div>
           <div class="footer">
                <div>Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div>
          </div>




</apex:page>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? By the way, there is no ASAP in this community

Answer (score 0):

For displaying Header and Footer you can try this:-

```
<head>
            <style type="text/css" media="print">
                   @page {
                             @top-center {
                                   content: element(header);
                           }
                           @bottom-left {
                                 content: element(footer);
                           }
                        }
                                 div.header {
                                  padding: 10px;
                                  position: running(header);
                       }
                   div.footer {
                            display: block;
                         padding: 5px;
                           position: running(footer);
                  }
                                 .pagenumber:before {
                                    content: counter(page);
                   }
                               .pagecount:before {
                         content: counter(pages);
                    }
                </style>
          </head>
       <div class="header">
          <div>Account name is: {!Account.name} ----------- and the date is {!TODAY()}</div>
       </div>
       <div class="footer">
            <div>Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
           <p>Actual page body information.</p>
      </div>
```

Note:- You can change the position and content according to your need by changing the values inside style tag.

For adding Image on Your pdf you can use this:-

```
<table  width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td align='right' width='60%'></td>
            <td align='right' width='40%'><apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.yourimage}" width="100PX" height="30PX"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here also you can adjust the position according to your requirement by changing the width and align values. You need to save your image in a static resource.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do all of what you're asking is to use standard HTML. PDFs rendered in Salesforce only support HTML 4.1 and CSS 2.1 which means they'll work best when you use Tables and not Visualforce. In fact, using Pageblocks is not recommended.

You can use styletags provided they're limited to styles supported under CSS 2.1. You can also use a separate Table for your header and a different one for the body. You can further nest both tables if you want or need to, just be careful of padding an margins.

Since I see you want your PDF to paginate, you'll want to do something like the below for the CSS in your table and header:

Add these to your `apex:page` definition:

```
sidebar="false"
showHeader="false"

table {
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
}

//puts a header at the start of each new page where a table crosses a page boundary.

// Then format the content for your PDF along the lines as shown below and adjust your CSS accordingly


<table>            
    <apex:repeat value= value="{!quotes.QuoteLineItem}" var="QuoteLineItem">
        <tr>
            <th>"item"</th>
            <th>"listprice"</th>
            <th>"discount"</th>
            <th>"description"</th>
            <td>"quote"</td>
            <td>{!quotelineitem.listprice}</td>
            <td>{!quotelineitem.discount}</td>
            <td>{!quotelineitem.description}</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

You can add another table above and below to hold your header and footer. You could possibly do the footer only using CSS since it doesn't change with the page number. A lot has to do with whether or not you plan to use borders in your table. There are equivalent -fs CSS commands that can be used for both.